# Modifying street view code, cannot substitute variable as argument

Tags: javascript, google-street-view

edit1= clearifying sample code
edit2= well this is getting embarassing, now I will post the actual code

I am trying to make a custom interior streetview. I am attempting to convert custom interior shot to be relative to arbitrary starting position by substituting the argument of the function below with variable, but would break the streetview. I am not familiar with javascript.

```
description:"TEST TEST TEST TSET",latLng:new google.maps.LatLng(54.156654,69.696969)
```

runs fine.

```
var demolat = 34.995348; // declared at beginning of function
var demolon = 135.7395;
var wlat = demolat;
var wlon = demolon;

.. lots of code .. // lots of code goes here

description:"TEST TEST TEST TSET",latLng:new google.maps.LatLng(wlat,wlon)
```

does not work.

full code

the script would not work properly when replaced line described above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
 charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" code="maps_code">

        var initPosPanoID,initPosPanoData,streetView,map_canvas;
        function initialize(){

        var neeclat = 35.564157;
        var neeclon = 139.714947;

        //var demolat = 34.995138;
        //var demolon = 135.739689;

        var demolat = 34.995348;
        var demolon = 135.7395;

        var wlat = demolat;
        var wlon = demolon;

        swbound = new google.maps.LatLng(wlat-0.0003,wlon-0.0003);
        nebound = new google.maps.LatLng(wlat+0.0003,wlon+0.0003);

        var initPos=new google.maps.LatLng(wlat,wlon);
        var mapOptions={zoom:14,center:initPos,mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
        var mapDiv=document.getElementById("map_canvas");
        map_canvas=new google.maps.Map(mapDiv,mapOptions);


        var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swbound,nebound);

        var overlay=new google.maps.GroundOverlay("./5Bc3IIj.jpg",bounds);
        overlay.setMap(map_canvas);
        var streetViewOptions={pov:{zoom:1,heading:161,pitch:-2.6}};
        var streetViewDiv=document.getElementById('streetview_canvas');
        streetViewDiv.style.fontSize="15px";
        streetView=new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(streetViewDiv,streetViewOptions);
        streetView.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(mapDiv);
        google.maps.event.trigger(map_canvas,"resize");
        map_canvas.setStreetView(streetView);
        streetView.registerPanoProvider(getCustomPanorama);
        var streetViewInitPos=new google.maps.LatLng(wlat,wlon);
        // var streetViewInitPos=new google.maps.LatLng(34.995348,135.7395);
        var streetviewService=new google.maps.StreetViewService();
        var radius=50;
        streetviewService.getPanoramaByLocation(streetViewInitPos,radius,function(result,status){
                if(status==google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK){
                    initPosPanoID=result.location.pano;
                    initPosPanoData=result;
                    streetView.setPosition(result.location.latLng);
                    map_canvas.panTo(result.location.latLng);
                }
            }
        );
        google.maps.event.addListener(streetView,"links_changed",createCustomLink);
        var map_marker=new google.maps.Marker({map:map_canvas});
        google.maps.event.addListener(streetView,"position_changed",function(){
            var position=this.getPosition();
            var map_bounds=map_canvas.getBounds();
            map_canvas.panTo(position);
            });
        }
    function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(panoID,zoom,tileX,tileY){
        return"./"+panoID+'/'+tileX+'-'+tileY+'_s1.jpg';
    }
    function getCustomPanorama(panoID){
        var streetViewPanoramaData={
            links:[],copyright:'',tiles:{
                tileSize:new google.maps.Size(2048,1024),worldSize:new google.maps.Size(2048,1024),centerHeading:0,getTileUrl:getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
            }
        };
        switch(panoID){
        case initPosPanoID:
            return initPosPanoData;
        case"Position_S":

            //var tmp = new google.maps.LatLng(wlat,wlon);
            streetViewPanoramaData["location"]={

                description:"TEST TEST TEST TSET",latLng:new google.maps.LatLng(3,3)
            };
            streetViewPanoramaData["copyright"]=""
            break;


        case"Position_SW":
            streetViewPanoramaData["location"]={
                description:"TEST TEST TEST TSET",latLng:new google.maps.LatLng(3,3)
            };
            streetViewPanoramaData["copyright"]=""
            break;


        }
        if("location"in streetViewPanoramaData){
            streetViewPanoramaData.location.pano=panoID;
            return streetViewPanoramaData;
        }
    }
    function createCustomLink(){
        var links=streetView.getLinks();
        var panoID=streetView.getPano();
        var currentPos=streetView.getPosition();
        switch(panoID){
            case initPosPanoID:
                links.push({description:"テストエリアへ",pano:"Position_S"});
                break;
            case"Position_S":
                links.push({description:"外へ",pano:initPosPanoID});
                links.push({description:"SWへ",pano:"Position_SW"});
                break;
            case"Position_SW":
                links.push({description:"Sへ",pano:"Position_S"});
                break;

        }
        if(links.length){    //compute directional pointer label.
            var linkPano;
            for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
                linkPano=getCustomPanorama(links[i].pano);
                if(linkPano!==undefined){
                    links[i].heading=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(currentPos,linkPano.location.latLng);
                }
            }
            return links;
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);


</script>
  <style type="text/css">html,body{width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
position:absolute}#frame,#streetview_canvas{width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative}#map_canvas{width:250px;
height:250px;
border:2px solid gray;
background-color:#fff}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="streetview_canvas"></div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The cause is probably in the `....` part, not on your use of variables. Do you see any errors on the browser developer console?

Comment: sorry, I've clarified the sample a bit.

Comment: The variables are called `mylat` and `mylon` in the first example but `wlat` and `wlon` in the second.

Comment: I double checked but it's still not working. Now I have provided the full code.

Comment: What's not working? http://jsbin.com/AcUNuyo/1/edit